# GNU Make invoked from top directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a directory named `experiments` and subdirectories with separate experiments, e.g. `2018-08-20`, `2018-08-21`. Each subdirectory contains a Python script that I run with screen using:

```
screen -L -dm -S experiment python script.py
```

*I wonder if I could have a* `Makefile` *in the* `experiments` *directory that would automate this command*. 
I know that I could have a `Makefile` in each subdirectory, but this is feeding to git too much repetitive stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can. As you do not give much details I will assume that:

1. **Any** sub directory of `experiments` containing a `script.py` python script is an experiment.
2. You want to re-run **all** experiments each time you invoke `make`.

The following should be a good starting point:

```
EXPDIRS := $(dir $(shell find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name script.py))
EXPS    := $(addsuffix .done,$(EXPDIRS))

.PHONY: all $(EXPS)

all: $(EXPS)

$(EXPS): %.done:
    cd $* && screen -L -dm -S experiment python script.py
```

Explanations:

- The `EXPDIRS` make variable is set using the `find` utility and the `dir` make function (to remove the file name part of the returned paths). Example: `./experimentC/ ./experimentA/`.
- The `EXPS` make variable is set by adding `.done` to each word in `EXPDIRS`. Example: `./experimentC/.done ./experimentA/.done`.
- The targets listed in `EXPS`, plus the `all` target are declared as phony, meaning that even if a file with that name exists already and is up to date, make will rerun its building rule.
- `all` depends on all targets listed in `EXPS`. If you run just `make` or `make all`, make will run the rules of all experiments, possibly in parallel if you invoke make with, for example, the `-j4` option, and you have 4 cores on your computer.
- Finally, the static pattern rule `$(EXPS):...` tells make what to do in order to build the targets listed in `EXPS`:

  - Go to the experiments directory (the `$*` make automatic variable expands as the stem of the `%.done` pattern).
  - Run your python script.

Possible improvements:

1. Run experiments if and only if they have not been run already or if their input data changed since the last time they have been run. Let's assume that the input data are only the python script (easy to modify, if needed). We will use an empty file named `experimentA/.done` to mark an experiment as done and remember when. Then, the following should avoid useless experiment runs:

   ```
   EXPDIRS := $(dir $(shell find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -name script.py))
   EXPS    := $(addsuffix .done,$(EXPDIRS))

   .PHONY: all

   all: $(EXPS)

   $(EXPS): %.done: %script.py
       cd $* && screen -L -dm -S experiment python script.py
       touch $@

   clean:
       rm -f $(EXPS)
   ```

Comment: Running the builds inside `screen` is kind of weird. Traditionally you would just run the build in a background with output to a log. `screen` lets you interact with the job and etc which is not desirable if you want completely predictable and reproducible builds.

Comment: @triplee: I fully agree.